# HTML 5 datalist with image

Tags: html, image, datalist

I google it but no luck.
How to add image on result ?

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

As [per the specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element), the *datalist* element allows either *phrasing content* or zero or more  *elements*.

> The datalist element can be used in two ways. In the simplest case, the datalist element has just option element children.
>
> In the more elaborate case, the datalist element can be given contents that are to be displayed for down-level clients that don't support datalist. In this case, the option elements are provided inside a select element inside the datalist element.

The phrasing content you are allowed to provide is there as a backup in the case where the browser doesn't support the datalist element.